# What is the best programmatically approach to display images/icons horizontally?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to place the icons / images horizontally in a view that is intended to show details. Maximum number of pictures per row is 6 pieces and I want to have a mechanism that manage line breaks or similar automatically. I suspect it is a custom cell that solves this?

I have tried the following code below, but the images above to add another when I reload the view. Furthermore, the cell's height is not adjusted by the view that the code returned.

```
-(UIImageView *)fillView{
    collage = nil;
    collage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 7, 0, 0)] autorelease];

    int rowCounter = 0;
    int colCounter = 0;
    int nrOfPictures = [paymentImages count];

        //max 6 images per row
    while (nrOfPictures > 0) {
        while (colCounter <= 6 && nrOfPictures != 0) {
            UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[paymentImages objectAtIndex:nrOfPictures-1]];
            CGRect frame = iv.frame;
            frame.origin.x = (frame.size.width + 4) * colCounter;
            frame.origin.y = (frame.size.height + 4) * rowCounter;
            iv.frame = frame;
            [collage addSubview:iv];
            [iv release];

            colCounter++;
            nrOfPictures--;
            if (colCounter > 6) {
                colCounter = 0;
                rowCounter++;
            }
        }
    }   
    return collage;
}
```

Can someone head me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out this project. http://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser